# How can I start my application in a more convenient way?

Tags: scripts

I am new in Ubuntu. I have an application which I open in the following way. I type in the console:

```
cd ~/MyDirectory
./myapp +some arguments
```

How can I find a solution, so I could launch my application without typing these commands in the console every time? I am thinking of a script, like a bat-script or .lnk in windows.

In other similar questions I didn't find a solution because there was only some mention and discussion of scripting. I didn't find how I can use "cd" command in other questions, and this question is not duplicate of others I suggest.

Comment: @steeldriver, no, i didn't found solution at this question. there are no anything about cd command and running app via script.

Comment: #1 Do you **want** the solution to be an icon you can click on your desktop, or will this be something which you need/want to run from the command prompt? #2 How often will the argument change?

Comment: The conversation (safely in this case) assumes there is a desktop. Quite often in the scripting world there will not be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A script is quite overkill.

Use a .desktop file like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/bin/bash -c "cd ~/MyDirectory && myapp some_arguments"
Name=Some App
Type=Application
```

- Save it as `some_app.desktop`
- Make it executable and double click

N.B.

The question is if it needs to be run from its own directory or not. If not, the command could even be simpler:

```
Exec='/home/MyUserName/MyDirectory/myapp' some_arguments
```

Comment: Really thank you. `.desktop` file is enough for this task.

Comment: @allo If OP asks for a solution, which isn't the optimal one for his problem, but he isn't aware a better one exists, you should give him the better solution for his problem if you know one. If you don't see that you are quite missing the point on what an answer should be here.

Comment: @dessert Thanks for the edit. We might have to deal with paths with spaces :)

Comment: You might want to write `./myapp …` instead of just `myapp …` because the current directory, `.`, by default is _not_ part of the PATH variable.

Comment: @allo Please feel free to add your own answer if you think the existing ones are not sufficient.

Comment: @JacobVlijm can you look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130775/open-any-file-with-specific-program if you have time?

Comment: @DKBose quite frankly, I don't get his issue, but he is using terrible/deprecated code :)

Comment: @fabby The answer from leonid is sufficient, so no need to add another answer. And personally I think this answer is an elegant solution, but the answer from leonid answers the actual question.

Comment: The discussion is moot now: the OP decided that this was the actual answer to his question.  **0:-)** @allo

Answer (score 14):

Create a file with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/MyDirectory
./myapp +some arguments
```

Then make it executable:

```
chmod u+x scriptname
```

Now you can call this script like this: `/pathtoscript/scriptname`

*You can combine this with [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1131791/449979) by v010dya, and put this script in any `bin` that is in the $PATH, so both calling methods are possible: in the shell in any directory type `scriptname` or use the desktop shortcut explained below. Just change `/pathtoscript` to the actual placement of the script.*

Make a shortcut to the script, place it in `~/.local/share/applications/` and name it like somename.desktop with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Script
Comment=
Keywords=Script
Exec=/pathtoscript/scriptname
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=true
Type=Application
Icon=preferences-system
Categories=GTK;Development;
StartupNotify=false
```

Then it will appear in the applications list

Comment: Your answer is working, thank you. But really sorry, script is too hard, I didn't knew about it. And my answer was concretically in script but not in just finding any way of solution. I will +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have already found a solution that you can double click on, there's a solution that makes it more trivial to run from command line:

### Step 1 - Write a script

This is already covered by [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130358/216568) of [LeonidMew](https://askubuntu.com/users/449979/leonidmew), i will copy it here:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/MyDirectory
./myapp +some arguments
```

and then

```
chmod u+x scriptname
```

### Step 2 - Make it easy to execute

You need to create a directory `~/bin` and make **bash** search it for commands. So in terminal we write:

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv scriptname ~/bin
vim ~/.profile
```

Here i am doing everything in terminal, you can of course create a directory `dir` in your home directory and also move your script there via graphical tools that you are comfortable with. Also i am using **vim** as an editor, but it is a little difficult for beginners to use, i would advise you to learn, but you can just use a different editor (even graphical) to edit `.profile` inside your home directory, note that this file is hidden by default.

You need to add the following to an end of that file

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

If you are using **vim** you press <kbd>i</kbd> to start adding text, and then <kbd>Esc</kbd> to end adding. After that you input `:wq` to write file and exit. Or, as i have already said, use a more simple editor.

### Step 3 - Enjoy

Now, it will not matter what directory you are in, you can always just type `scriptname` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can also place other scripts and applications that you want to be executable in `~/bin`.

Comment: You wrote how to exit of vim, +1 Just kidding, nice answer. Your solution is useful. It still possible to create .desktop file, to run script from apps list or menu(depending on DE). After patching .profile logout/login is needed. Also home can be mounted with noexec option, in this case its needed to put script in /usr/local/bin/ (using sudo).