# How to make a .sh script automatically run in the terminal?

Tags: bash, scripts

How do I make a Shell Script that when doube-clicked automatically runs in the terminal? In other words: I am too lazy to constantly do

```bsh
cd Desktop
chmod +x myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

, so is there any way to auto open the terminal for a bash script?

Comment: If you `chmod +x` a file, as long as the file system can store the data correctly (ie. a native file-system), the execute permission will be set, and double-clicking on the file will attempt execute.  I just created a file.sh, `chmod +x`, then in my preferred `pcmanfm-qt` a double-click of it asks if I want to run in terminal (I answer yes & it runs). If i use `thunar` (my second favorite) it'll open in an editor  -- using a different file manager may be all you need.  (note: *I'm using pcmanfm-qt & thunar as examples; I'm running Lubuntu, but also like Xubuntu - hence those choices*)

Comment: @guiverc What? I did chmod+x and it just opens the text editor. I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Using standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  you'll likely be running GNOME & using `nautilus`, and it's doing what `thunar` did on my 19.04 box (opened in an editor; `gedit` probably in your case & it was something else in mine).  I opened `nautilus` (Files it is called within gnome menus) &  I didn't see any way to make nautilus do what you want (but I'm not a gnome person, so rarely use it & others may have ideas I've not discovered if you wait).   My answer was to try another File.Manager/File.Browser.  I tried `dolphin` and it too has a "*Run in Konsole*" option (Konsole is the KDE terminal)

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I start my application in a more convenient way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130354/how-can-i-start-my-application-in-a-more-convenient-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a launcher for the script. You would be able to run the script from the activities menu in GNOME (click it) and from the directory the file is saved in. This would  be a .desktop file. e.g. Example.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Example
Exec=/path/to/executable_script
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=/optional/path/to/icon.png
```

Make the file executable. When placed in /usr/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications, GNOME will add the .desktop file to the activities menu.

Now you just have to click the launcher in the activities menu and your script will run. The terminal will close after the script has run to its end.